# Scala Combinator Parser not working with spaces

Tags: scala, parsing, combinators

Why does this simple example of a scala combinator parser fail?

```
def test: Parser[String] = "&lt; " ~> ident <~ " &gt;"
```

When I provide the following string:

```
"&lt; a &gt;"
```

I get this error:

```
[1.8] failure: ` &gt;' expected but `&' found

&lt; a &gt;
       ^
```

Why is it tripping up on the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using `RegexParsers`. In [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers), you can find that:

> The parsing methods call the method skipWhitespace (defaults to true)
>   and, if true, skip any whitespace before each parser is called.

To change this:

```
object MyParsers extends RegexParsers {
  override def skipWhitespace = false

  //your parsers...
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD, THANK YOU!  Why is this the default :(